# Where do I find the latest upgrade options for my phone?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, 4.3-jelly-bean, huawei

So, I got the Huawei Ascend G6 and I haven't been able to upgrade since Jelly Bean. Last month, my sister who bought the exact same phone just a week after I did, came to me complaining how her interface "suddenly" looked totally different. It looked like she updated her phone to Kitkat. She told me, the phone asked her to upgrade and she did.

Now, even when I try, I can't seem to upgrade. When I press "online update", it just says "No updates found". So how do I figure out, what the latest upgrade possibilities are for my phone? Maybe I did get a slightly older model after all, which can't upgrade for some reason?

We both haven't rooted our phone and I'm not planning on doing so.

Comment: check this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/ascend-g6/general/official-kit-kat-4-4-rom-g6-l11-t3052035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be due to your country or we says `(Rom Region)`.

Sometimes, it is better to download and update that phone with manually installation.

**So, the thing is how you can find the latest version?**

you just have to check these links for the latest roms:

> http://forum.xda-developers.com/ascend-g6

or go to the official website and search about that phone with typing the exactly name and goto downloads section.for-ex:

> http://consumer.huawei.com/kh/support/products/downloads/ascend-g6-4g-kh.htm

P.s: if you couldn't find any new rom for your phone, another option is using **CustomRoms**